# Spreading server load with a mini CDN

Tags: php, cdn

Using a caching plugin for my wordpress site reduced the server load by quite alot, but I'm trying to reduce it even more. The caching plugin creates a static html file that can be re-used rather than re-creating it with php every single request.

I want to copy this static file to multiple servers so it can be served from multiple locations, thus spreading server load.

## The concept

[image: concept]

I'm basically doing it like this:

**Main server:**

```
//Echo's what the pointer server will echo, which echo's what the sub-server echo's (which is the stored html file's content)
echo file_get_contents("http://$pointerserver?f=$fileNameWeAreRequesting";
```

**Pointer server:**

```
if(isset($_GET['f'])){ $requestedfile = $_GET['f']; }
/* Redirect user to file */
if(isset($_GET['redirect']))
{
    //Filename example: file.html (shares same filename as it's original, 
    //but the content holds a string of sub-servers that host the file, seperated by a comma)
    $servers = file_get_contents("filelocations/$requestedfile");
    $pieces = explode(",", $servers); //Sub-Servers to array
    //Check for online server
    foreach ($pieces as $server)
    {
        if(file_get_contents("servercheck/$server") == "1") //Check if sub-server online
        {
            /* Echo file from sub-server NOW */
            echo file_get_contents("http://$server?f=$requestedfile"); //Echo's whatever the sub-server echo's
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sub-server**

```
/* Provide requested file */
echo file_get_contents("files/$requestedfile"); //Echo's the static html page stored on the sub-server
```

1. Does this even reduce the load on the main server at all? Or does file_get_contents work in such a way that the main server ends up "parsing"(putting together the file for html output) the file anyway.
2. How can I add a check so that if the sub-server is offline without the pointer server knowing about it, we serve the static html file from the main server instead.

## Making the main server ready for this

[image: main-server-cdn-ready]

The caching plugin handles the making of the static file, so for sending it I was thinking:

**Main server:**

```
//This doesn't send anything physical, just instructions to what file the pointer server needs to retrieve and then copy over to the sub-severs.
echo file_get_contents("http://$pointerserver?propagate&f=$fileNameWeAreRequesting";
```

**Pointer server:** (I know this doesn't work, it's to illustrate the idea)

```
    if(isset($_GET['f'])){ $requestedfile = $_GET['f']; }
/* Propagate file to sub-servers */
if(isset($_GET['propagate']))
{
    if ($handle = opendir('subservers/')) //Retrieve all available sub-servers
    {
        while (false !== ($server = readdir($handle))) //For-each subserver, send the file
        {
            if ($server != "." && $server != "..") 
            {
                /* CREATE AUTO-SUBMIT FORM HERE TO POST FILE CONTENTS (CONCEPT) */
                action="http://$server/receivefile.php?f=$requestedfile&send"
                $postThisStuff = file_get_contents("http://www.mainserver.xx/cache/$requestedfile"); //Reads the file contents from the main server so it can send it over to the sub-server
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The sub-server**

```
/* Receive file */
if(isset($_GET['send']))
{
    //Write received post date to file
    $fh = fopen("files/$requestedfile", 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = $_POST['thefile'];
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
    die();
}
```

So my third and final question is; is this copying method a good approach, resource-wise? The static files on the main server rarely change, only when someone posts a comment or an article is edited (or a new one added) but it's still important to be resource-conserving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, I had to up-vote the answer for the great presentation. Your idea is not bad either, but still: to *answer* your question: **"Don't do it!"**.

1. If the WP plugin is configured to write actual HTMLs of the page, use them first? E.g. bypass the entire PHP stack by checking if a html file exists which could be served for the current request. Apache, Nginx or Lighttpd support this by means of URL rewriting (or even in core in terms of nginx). [Side-note: I have no idea which webserver or Wordpress plugin you use, so I omitted config snippets.]
2. If this doesn't help already, or if this is not enough, distribute the content using a reverse proxy (like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)). It's easy to define your *main server* as the origin server and let various Varnish servers in front of it handle the rest.
3. If Varnish is not good enough and your site can be served from a CDN entirely, have a look at someone like [edgecast](http://www.edgecast.com/) ([speedyrails](http://www.speedyrails.com/cdn) is a reseller of them). They allow you to do transparent caching:

   - http://my-blog.com is pointed to edgecast's server directly
   - you configure edgecast to check http://mainserver.my-blog.com if no cache is filled
   - configure cache headers to avoid frequent lookups
   - they also allow you to purge the cache (for when you update your blog)
4. If all of the above is not for you, I suggest you check out [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/). They do what you want to do (and more). I'm test-driving them myself, works flawlessly so far.

Comment: These are all very good tips, thank you. 3 and 4 are a no-go for me personally because it's way cheaper (and interesting) to do things myself. Varnish looks like it may be exactly what I'm looking for, so going to give that a whirl later. Just out of curiosity, why "Don't do it!"? Because the alternatives are all easier/error-proof or because my methods (file_get_contents) wouldn't reduce server load to begin with?

Comment: Cloudflare is free, btw. (But maybe not always.)

Comment: Sorry, to answer why not. I think for various reasons: mainserver is the SPOF in your picture. I don't think this will really take as much load as you want off of it since PHP is still invoked - no matter what.

Also, a HTTP request from other servers adds more latency to the current request (for little benefit).

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide an example of Debian6 + Lighttpd completely bybassing php by checking for the html with url rewriting? I just noticed that even if I make wp_super_cache (the plugin) return a blank page, the serverload still rakes up to 100% when I connect with 100 clients at the same time. Because php-fpm processes are still made.

Comment: http://tempe.st/2008/04/lighttpd-and-wp-supercache-now-you-can/ < In this case, you need something like that. Does that work for you?

Comment: Whoa, that took forever to get working, but it's great! One question though, if files served are always static, I don't think wp_super_cache ever renews them. I guess I'll have to write a script that deletes all cached files every X seconds, or is that nonsense?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about wp-super-cache, but I remember there are hooks to e.g. delete an entry when it's updated. Or to delete the homepage and archive pages so new entries are shown and changes are reflected.